# iAd or AdMob for iPhone/iPad development?

Tags: iphone, admob, iad

Is there still a point to use AdMob? Has it been or will it be banned by Apple? Is there an third-party interface solution that allows me to switch between the services later on server side?

Answer (score 23):

In fact it is very easy to use **both** even in the **same application**!

You can find a detailed explanation at this site:
http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_mixing_ads.php

But in-short the idea behind it is to:

1. Create an iAd banner and an Admob banner in viewDidLoad
2. Only the iAd banner gets registered
3. When iAd fails Admob banner gets registered
4. If iAd would become active again, the Admob banner will disappear

It even uses a sliding effect to hide and show the advertisements in the bottom of the screen.

So far I can't give a correct number on the revenue, but I can say that the **fill rate for iAd is around 30% and for Admob around 95%**

Hope this helps you out!

Regards,
Luc

Comment: +1 for the info about the fill rate.

Comment: Check out this link about a guy who says iAd fails most of the time and he uses admob to supplement the failures. http://www.hung-truong.com/blog/2011/02/07/iad-vs-admob-clicks-fill-rate-impressions-ecpm-and-revenue/

Answer (score 2):

You can use both (not in the same app!) but be carefull in what you pick!

I do my homeworks, trying both (on different apps of course) and asking around to friends.
There's not a final verdict of course. Sdk are pretty both easy, but of course iAD is completely integrated in itunesconnect, so you don't have to deal with different sites, registration and so on... but ok, is something you do once and forget, so not a big deal.

For my experience iAd give bit more money for banner shown, but AdMob have an incredible superior fill rate! I you're an "international" developer iAd is (till now, end of 2010) a poor option: my app have about 25% US customers and a forthy-somthing fill rate there. Add some more sparse filled impressions here and there, I net a 10% fill rate world-wide!
The other app, with AdMob, Italian market only, have a 66% fill rate... in a country where iAd is still not available!

So 'till Apple don't go worldwide for ads i suggest to put your focus on WHERE you plan to distribuite your apps...

Just my 2 cents

Answer (score 1):

Better to go with iAds. No one knows, apple releases an update and your application starts breaking. They are very much into it and for wiping out their competitors, its high possibility that they do it very soon.

Ultimately its your choice, you can use any.

Answer (score 0):

An idea.  What about using a combination of the two?  So far, the story on iAds is that the fill rate is very low.  Apple suggests moving the BannerView off-screen when the ad request is not filled (great idea).  After moving the BannerView off-screen, why not move an AdMob ad into the void.  Not sure if mixing ad platforms would cause poor user experience, but it might be worth considering.

Just a thought.

Andrew

Comment: I imagine it would against a terms of service.

Comment: another reason for trying the approach I mentioned is that you could enable AdMob ads to display for any users who have not upgraded their devices to iOS 4.0+.  For that reason, I think Apple might actually allow it (i.e. because Apple doesn't have an ad solution for iOS 3.x)