# xcode 4 - iAd and AdMob

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, admob, iad

Is there a way to integrate iAd and AdMob in one project so that if iAd is not being served, AdMob will be served?

I really appreciate an example code if there is any.

Comment: I have just found the answer here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384028/iad-or-admob-for-iphone-ipad-development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [`bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009581-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4) which is called when the banner view fails to load a new iAd advertisement:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     // Load AdMob ad
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know..what happen if there is new iAD ready to show and an admob is still showing?

Comment: You can remove the existing admob when the new iAd is available in the method `bannerViewDidLoadAd:`.

Answer (score 1):

Admob currently have a beta running with a mediation SDK in it that will handle this automatically. Give it a few weeks and it should be out of beta.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.adwhirl.com/ is an easy way to do just that, I use it with iAd's and AdMob and it works very well.